# Is there any way to add a NSColorWell colour picker in Qt?

Tags: macos, qt, qt4

Mac OS X has a standard colour picking button (Cocoa class: NSColorWell).

Is there any way to use these for the Mac version of my product in Qt?

I am using Qt 4.8.1 on Mac OS X 10.6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[QMacCocoaViewContainer](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmaccocoaviewcontainer.html) can handle scenarios like this. The basic usage is:

```
class MacControl : public QMacCocoaViewContainer {
  Q_OBJECT

 public:
  explicit MacControl(QWidget *parent = NULL)
    : QMacCocoaViewContainer(NULL, parent) {
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    NSColorWell *colors = [[NSColorWell alloc] init];
    // set properties on color well
    setCocoaView(color);
    [colors release];
    [pool release];
  }
```

Actually, you probably won't be able to put it all in one file if you are compiling for multiple platforms. You would have a header file that declares a method that can be called from any platform, a `cpp` file that implements the method by calling the normal Qt color dialog for non-Mac, and an `mm` file that creates the Mac-specific widget and displays it.